# RDLC External Image works in ASP.NET but not in WPF

Tags: wpf, rdlc

I have lots of RDLC reports in an ASP.NET app, many generated dynamically (manual manipulation of .rdlc XML file).

Many have external images (EnableExternalImages=true, full https://... url of image passed to report as a parameter).

Reports and images work fine in ASP.NET app (via ReportViewer control).

I am now building a WPF app that uses the same code to generate PDF files from the .rdlc reports.

For the most part the reports work just fine in both ASP.NET and WPF. Both use LocalReport.Render("PDF") to generate a PDF file. The only exception is where external images are used - the report does not seem to be able to render external images in WPF. If I replace the external image with an embedded image it works fine. The URL is definitely correct in the WPF app (works if pasted into browser).

I have tried http and https, and "run as administrator" - same results. The actual error message is typically unhelpful and just seems to be a generic "something wrong" message ("The subreport 'Subreport1' could not be found at the specified location Custom1. Please verify that the subreport has Page 1").

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Doh! As usual the problem was my own stupid mistake, made worse by unhelpful error messages.

LocalReport.Render("PDF", ..., out warnings) has a version that includes an output parameter for Warnings which in this case gave me a precise reason for the malfunction: EnableExternalImages was NOT set as I thought (test all your ASSumptions!) (why don't they show this message in the report instead of the useless generic message, would have saved me a lot of time!).

EnableExternalImages turned out to be set in aspx markup, and not in the RDLC generator code, thus it worked in ASP.NET but not in WPF. I now set it in the code and it works in both apps as expected.

I have read many posts about external images not working in PDF - they definitely work just fine in PDF (and Word), at least with Microsfot.ReportViewer2015.Runtime v12.0.2.2402. What often does not work however is displaying the images in IE in the online (in-browser) preview of the report - half the time they show and half the time they do not show, but they always show in the PDF.